# Qual a melhor maneira de postar esse echo?

Tags: php

Qual a melhor maneira de postar esse echo? Sei que esta faltando alguma aspa, só não sei aonde coloca-la.

```
<?php

echo '<a href="page.php"><em>' <?php echo $locale->translate('ID'); ?> '</em></a>';

?>
```

Comment: <?php

echo '<a href="page.php"><em>'  $locale->translate('ID') '</em></a>';

?>  // Também não funcionou.

Comment: faltou colocar o ponto antes de $ e depois de ('ID').

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eu inverteria o código, deixaria o HTML chamando o php e não o contrário:

```
<a href="page.php"><em><?php echo $locale->translate('ID'); ?></em></a>'
```

Porém, se quiser printar a partir do PHP mesmo:

```
<?php

echo '<a href="page.php"><em>' . $locale->translate('ID') . '</em></a>';

?>
```

Comment: Funcionou 100%. Resolvido. Obrigado também ao @buback que também postou a solução correta.

Answer (score 5):

Você deve concatenar e não repetir o echo.

```
<?php
echo '<a href="page.php"><em>' . $locale->translate('ID') . '</em></a>';
?>
```